# How to move SharePoint designer developed workflow one site to another site?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

How to move SharePoint designer developed workflow one site to another site.
what are the steps by do i am follow .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is advisable to create a reusable workflow from designer, if you want to move to another site.

If you have created list workflow,
[here is good article](http://chanakyajayabalan.wordpress.com/2012/01/02/copyingmoving-sharepoint-2010-designer-workflows/) that demonstrates step by step guidelines to move SP designer list workflow from one site to another site.

Comment: Thank you Kunal Valecha ..!